# What does the em dash function here?

Tags: punctuation, em-dash

> Considering zinc's safety, people should consider taking zinc supplements, especially as they age—being sure to include copper in the proper balance.

What does the em dash function here? It does't seem like it is used as a parenthesis, as it ususally does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering zinc's safety, people should consider taking zinc supplements, especially as they age—being sure to include copper in the proper balance.

In the above sentence, the phrase after the em dash is amplifying the need of using/including copper in the mixture, just like someone puts emphasis in a paraphrase or poetic creation, that would otherwise lead to some chemical defect in the other mentioned metal, namely zinc.

This [article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/dash/) may come in handy for you.